# How to put .sequelizerc configuration in package.json?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, package.json

I rather not have multiple configuration files. So I'm trying to consolidate as much as possible.

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, this is a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)

Answer (score 0):

It's not being documented (at least not well documented) but looking into the source code of Sequelize-cli you can find an options-path parameter:

In your case use it like  `--options-path package.json`

Source code:
[cli/src/core/yargs.js](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/5633648ecb6d81b3fdeafadd5ee1c9e6fb350dd5/src/core/yargs.js)